# How to create Deedle based by rows in a loop?

Tags: c#, deedle

I have a custom XrecordTable with no key value pairs - how to create a deedle frame?
Thanks!

```
frame.AddColumn("Column1", new[] { 1, 2, 3 }); // Adding column with integer values
frame.AddColumn("Column2", new[] { "A", "B", "C" }); // Adding column with string values
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.